# matplotlib.pyplot.imsave backend

Tags: image, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, backend

I'm working in Spyder with matplotlib.pyplot and want to save numpy array to images.
The documentation of imsave() says, that the format to which I can save depends on the backend. So what exactly is the backend? I seem to be able to save .tiff images, but f.e. I want them to be saved as 8-bit tiffs instead of RGB-Tiffs. Any Idea where I can change that?

Comment: I am afraid that `imsave` will, whatever your array, apply a `cmap` to it and convert it to RGB format before saving, so there really is no way around getting an RGB TIFF with it. I don't like PIL, but it may be the better option for what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to save an array as a tiff (with no axis markers ect) from mat, you might be better off using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

(this assumes you are using `ipython --pylab`, so `rand` is defined)

write:

```
import PIL.Image as Image
im = Image.new('L',(100,100))
im.putdata(np.floor(rand(100,100) * 256).astype('uint8').ravel())
im.save('test.tif')
```

The `ravel()` is important, `putdata` expects a sequence (ie, 1D) not an array.

read :

```
im2 = Image.open('test.tif')
figure()
imshow(im2)
```

and the output file:

```
$ tiffinfo test.tif 
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 100 Image Length: 100
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Rows/Strip: 100
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I did not even think about using PIL because I so was stuck in my numpy box ;)