# Remove whitespace from matplotlib savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to read in a series of .bmp images and do some linear contrast adjustment based on a tip I got. These images are small, 112x112, and I want to them to come out looking exactly the same except contrast-adjusted. I've tried doing it with matplotlib, but no matter what I do I get white space around the border of the images. Here's the code I'm using:

```
# Open image and convert to array
oldImage = Image.open(f)
imageArray = np.array(oldImage)

# Preprocessing
vrange = stats.mquantiles(imageArray.flatten(),prob=[0.01,0.99])

# Plot and save
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(1,1)
fig.set_dpi(112)
plt.imshow(imageArray,cmap="gray",interpolation="Nearest",vmin=vrange[0],vmax=vrange[1]);
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(f[:-4] + "_adjusted.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Any tips for how to remove the padding? I've done some googling but nothing I've found has worked so far.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503725/matplotlib-pyplot-imsave-backend/14506028#14506028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do thresholding without matplotlib:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats.mstats as mstats

f = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/image.png')
name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
out = name+"_adjusted.png"

oldImage = Image.open(f).convert('L')
imageArray = np.array(oldImage)

vmin, vmax = mstats.mquantiles(imageArray.flatten(), prob=[0.01,0.99])

np.clip(imageArray, vmin, vmax, out=imageArray)
imageArray = (imageArray-vmin)*255/(vmax-vmin)
img = Image.fromarray(imageArray.astype('uint8'), 'L')
img.save(out)
```

This way, you do not have to define a figure size in inches, and a DPI and so forth. You just convert the PIL Image to a numpy array, do some math, and convert back to a PIL Image.

Comment: Can we do this without "Image" library? I don't have that in my Python distribution.

Comment: @JohnSmith: The `Image` module is provided by the PIL (or [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow)) package. There are [alternative modules](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=image+read&submit=search) for reading images such as [imageio](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), though -- disclaimer -- I've never used it. Some image formats such as [PBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) are simple enough for you to write your own image reader, but in general people install PIL (or, nowadays Pillow) to read images.

Answer (score 0):

add the following line before `plt.savefig()`:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0,0)
```

Comment: Most useful answer